# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op in my application

Tags: android

What is the solution for this problem?
Tried many solutions but failed.

```
  dependencies 
 { 
 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') 
 implementation files('libs/renderscript-v8.jar') 
 implementation files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar') 
 implementation 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
 implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' 
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' 
 implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'                
 implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image- 
 loader:1.9.5'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.okhttp:okhttp:20120626' 
 implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip- 
 library:1.3.15' 
 implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.5'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1' 
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' 
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
```

This is the error.

> Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}}

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's probably caused by *'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'*

I had the same problem with it. Actually, the library itself is pretty old and GitHub is archived, so I replaced it with https://github.com/vivchar/ViewPagerIndicator, but you can find a lot of similar libraries on eg android-arsenal.com